# Window controller close not remove window completely

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have two windows. In first window I create second one with the following code:

```
self.toolsWindowController = ToolsWindowController()
```

`ToolsWindowController` is a simple window that I load from Nib:

```
class ToolsWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override var windowNibName : NSNib.Name! {
        return NSNib.Name(rawValue: "ToolsWindow")
    }
}
```

Then in first window I close ToolWindow:

```
toolsWindowController?.close()
```

And window still exist. And after reopen window count increased.

```
print(NSApplication.shared.windows.count)
```

[image]

I tried this option, it didn't help. How to remove window completely from memory.

Comment: What do you mean, "still exist"? Is it visible on screen? Do you expect `toolsWindowController` to become `nil`? (It doesn't, you have to do that yourself.)

Comment: @ctietze After close window in `NSApplication.shared.windows` list. I want to completely remove it.

Comment: I tried to set variable = nil, didn't help

Comment: Looks like it use same previous nib file every time

Comment: No matter what Interface Builder says, check `window.isReleasedWhenClosed` is true; but since you use a `NSWindowController`, [autoreleasing will not happen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419062-isreleasedwhenclosed). Try to set `self.window = nil` in `ToolsWindowController.windowShouldClose(_:)`, then set `toolsWindowController = nil` in your code where you call `close()` to get rid of all possible strong references.

Comment: @ctietze getting reference error. But when do self.toolsWindowController = nil

Comment: In the line right after `toolsWindowController?.close()` -- the docs say as long as you use an `NSWindowController`, closing the window will not remove it. You either need to remove it _from_ the window controller, remove the window controller itself, or both.

Comment: @ctietze yes, I read about this in article that you gave. But It is weird why I get error when try to set toolsWindowController = nil  or even when in another function trying to create new window controller and assign to this variable

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found a solution to make a `window = nil` in `deinit` method. Also in my case I have a `window.styleMask.insert(.fullScreen)` full screen file mask that creates overlay window object. So you need to remove it too.

```
class ToolsWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override var windowNibName : NSNib.Name! {
        return NSNib.Name(rawValue: "ToolsWindow")
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        self.window?.styleMask.remove(.fullScreen)
        self.window = nil
    }
}
```

And then `self.toolsWindowController=nil` do the job